# How to associate country table in job model cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have jobs and countries table

```
Table - Jobs 
Column name = pickup_region1

Table - Countries 
Column name = id
```

I am using find query on job table..
How to associate country table on job model so that when I run select query on job it automatically bind this relation
jobs.country_id = Countries.id

```
     class Job extends AppModel { 

    public $belongsTo = array(
    'country' => array(
          'className' => 'country',
          'primaryKey' => 'id',
          'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
          'dependent' => true,
          'conditions' => '',
          'fields' => '',
          'order' => '',
          'limit' => '',
          'offset' => '',
          'exclusive' => '',
          'finderQuery' => '',
          'counterQuery' => ''
    ) );
}
```

Comment: try `'className' => 'Country',` here `Country` should be CamelCase

Answer (score 0):

Model for countries should be: `Country.php` for table `countries`,
when you stick to convention, this statment is enought:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Country');
```

If you have `$recursive` set to `-1`, you need to tell cake which association should use when, like that:
([more about `$recursive`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive))

```
$this->Job->contain(array('Country'));
```

And next query on `Job` will arrive with `Country`
You can also contain inside `find` query:

```
$this->Job->find('all', array(
  ...
  'contain' => array('Country')
));
```

[more info](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Comment: but this shows database error Unknown column 'Job.country_id' in 'on clause'..how can i replace the column name with my column..bcoz in my Job table column name is pickup_region1.

Comment: @kayanew `'foreignKey' => 'pickup_region1'`

Comment: @kayanew Why don't you stick to cake conventions?

Comment: no but i want to do this inside model not in controller..bcoz i need to find this data multiple times..so can u plz help me to to write the same on model..